# How to refresh listview when click an item on listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a custom adapter extends from arrayadapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        holder.ivItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivItem);
        holder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        holder.ivArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrow);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvName.setText(item.get(position).getName());
    holder.tvPrice.setText(item.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.ivItem.setImageBitmap(item.get(position).getAvatar());
    holder.ivArrow.setImageDrawable(item.get(position).getArrow());
    holder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.get(position).getIcon());


            holder.ivIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        /*...My code...*/
    }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

I try to click on item `ivIcon`, a row of `listview` will be removed and `listview` should refresh, but I don't have way to refresh listview. I need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choices are:

- Use the functions of the ArrayAdapter to modify the underlying List (add, insert, remove, clear, etc.)
- Re-create the ArrayAdapter with the new List data. (Uses a lot of resources and garbage collection.)
- Create your own class derived from BaseAdapter and ListAdapter that allows changing of the underlying List data structure.
- Use the notifyDataSetChanged every time the list is update. To call it on the UI-Thread use the runOnUiThread method of the Activity. Then notifyDataSetChanged will work.

Example

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter());
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: I must using thread for instance to update when the list change?

Comment: No way to refresh adapter in getView()?

Comment: I am trying to rename a filename within the ListView but it doesn't update unless I leave the Activity and come back to it again. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

Suppose that your have adapter like

```
 ListView = listview;
 customListView mcustomListView = new customListView(this);
```

when you click on list item in getView

```
 holder.ivIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         customListView  mcustomListView = (customListView ) mlvItem.getAdapter();
mcustomListView .notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
  }
```